# How do I install a coded WordPress theme into wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com, wordpress.com-themes

I am currently in the process of having my `wordpress.com` (not `.org`) theme designed and coded at `99designs.com`. They will install the theme for $199 USD or I can opt to do it myself.

Is it easy to install the WordPress theme yourself?

I imagine it would be just select the sandbox theme and upgrade to "edit css" and copy and paste the CSS code?

Maybe add a few image links etc.

Am I on the right track, or is there a lot more to it then that?

Comment: You could also check the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Awesome - didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems all you have to do is paste your own CSS. However, if the theme requires custom PHP or HTML, you will need to host Wordpress yourself (through a web host) which is much more complicated.

> If you purchase the Custom CSS Upgrade you can modify the stylesheet of any theme. Moreover, the Sandbox theme allows a great deal of flexibility and is a great option for skilled CSS artists looking to heavily modify the look and feel of any blog. Learn more about Editing CSS.
>
> The Custom CSS Upgrade, however, does NOT grant you the ability to edit the core PHP and HTML template files of any theme. If you require this functionality, please consider moving your blog to a web host that supports theme code modifications, suitable hosts can be found here.
>
> [source](http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/editing-themes/)

See also: [Uploading Custom Themes](http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/adding-new-themes/)